# Python 2.7 Subset a groupby dataframe based on another groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 groupby dataframes (AUS_2016 and df_pitLaps, both grouped by driver ID) which have the same column ('lap'), and i am trying to subset AUS_2016 such that it does not contains values in that lap column in df_pitLaps for each driver.

To put it simply, I want to filter out pitlaps (laps with pit stop) for a particular race for each driver

I get a dataframe of True values grouped by driver ID, but I'm not sure how to proceed next.

AUS_2016:

[image]

df_pitLaps:

[image]

```
def clean_laps_no_pitlaps(data):
    """Filters out the pit laps."""
    df_pitLaps = df_pitStops.loc[df_pitStops['raceId'].isin(data['raceId'])]
    df_pitLaps.groupby("driverId")["lap"]
    data = data.groupby("driverId")["lap"]

    nopitlaps = lambda x: (
        [(lap != pitlap) for pitlap, lap in itertools.izip(x, data)])

    no_pitlaps_in_data = pd.DataFrame(data.apply(nopitlaps))

    return no_pitlaps_in_data
```

Calling the function:

```
clean_laps_no_pitlaps(AUS_2016)
```

This give this error:

> DeprecationWarning: elementwise != comparison failed; this will raise
>   an error in the future.

and below dataframe. I am not sure how to continue on from here to only filter laps for each driver that are  True (not pit laps).

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

I managed to resolve it by using another method which does not need groupby. I "vlooked-up" the laps with pit stops to df, then excluded these rows.

```
def no_pitlaps(df, df_pitLaps):
    """Returns a dataframe that excludes the pit laps of each driver"""

    data_pitlaps_mapped = pd.merge(df, df_pitLaps[['driverId', 'stop', 'lap']], how='left',
        left_on=['driverId','lap'], right_on=['driverId','lap'])

    return data_pitlaps_mapped.loc[~data_pitlaps_mapped.index.isin(data_pitlaps_mapped.dropna(subset = ['stop']).index)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to exclude all the laps in `AUS_2016` that appear in `df_pitLaps` that is simply done by:

```
AUS_2016[~AUS_2016['lap'].isin(df_pitLaps['lap'].unique())]
```

Comment: Hey @zipa, thanks but this does not filter out each driver's own pitlaps. For eg, vettel has pitstops on lap 18 and 36, but because hamilton has a pitlap on lap 20, lap 20 is removed from vettel's data too.

Comment: ,i managed to solve it by "vlookingup" the pit laps for each driver to a new dt and then doing an inverse dropna. see update above